# How do you do the IN (SQL) operation using underscore js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js

I am trying to query json using underscore js and im kinda stuck. I want to do an IN operation like from SQL but im not sure how to do it using the _.where function.

For example,

In SQL the query would be like:

```
where n = 10 AND color in ('red', 'pink', 'black');
```

But when writing this in underscore I can't do this (recordset is an array of objects)

```
_.where( recordset, { n: 10, color: 'red' || 'pink' || 'black'});
```

That just gives me objects where n = 10 and color is only red. Any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding what you've tried, the JS expression `'red' || 'pink' || 'black'` evaluates to `'red'`, so Underscore never even sees the `'pink'` and `'black'` parts of that expression. I'm not sure about Underscore, but maybe it lets you pass an array of values or something? Check the doco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let colors = ['red', 'pink', 'black']
let resultset = _.select(recordset, e => e.n === 10 && _.contains(colors, e.color))
```

or in older js

```
var resultset = _.select(recordset, function (e) {
    return e.n === 10 && _.contains(['red', 'pink', 'black'], e.color);
});
```

`_.select` takes an array as the first argument (equivalent to the `FROM` in SQL) and a function returning true/false as the second argument (equivalent to the `WHERE` in SQL).